# Can't enter name or biography during character creation

Tags: icewind-dale

When creating a character in Icewind Dale, I have no problems until I reach the biography and name entering. In both these screens I am unable to enter any letters, a small "b" enters continuously until there is no more space left and if I press delete another "b" takes its place. This happened when in Baldurs Gate II as well, but somehow was fixed by leaving the game and returning; this is not the case with Icewind Dale. I would really like to name my character, I dont really care about the biography. Any suggestions as to what could be causing this?

Answer (score -2):

I had this same problem.  I thought I'd disabled anti-virus, but actually my old antivirus program (Malware Bytes) was still running in the background.  Disabled that, now the game works great.